# How to create unique key by timestamp

Tags: r

I have a requirement to create dataframe rows with different columns like `userid, username, actionname, workprofile etc.` I need to store each row of dataframe into a database with Unique id.
I was thinking of creating a unique key using system `timestamp` to store along with each row so as to uniquely identify each entries into the table.

Please let me know if there are any functions/ approach that can be applied.
The language is R

Comment: If you are saving the dataframe to a database, then it is possible there is already an identity column.  If you want to create a key, then how about the `row.names`?  So for example if you wanted to create a variable for `iris` `iris$UniqueKey <- row.names(iris)`.  Without specifics of what data you have and what you have tried it is hard for people to help you.  Please post the code you have tried, and a sample of the data you have (you can create this with `dput`) and what you would like the expected output to be.

Comment: I think using timestamp as key is bad idea. Better you go with serial number or some random but unique string...

Comment: I am new to R and was trying UUIDgenerate(use.time = TRUE). But looking for some more option for adding unique identifier with each row.

Comment: a boring `id` column with some value automatically maintained by your database (e.g. `SERIAL` in postgres) would be the standard way to go.  having a separate `when_created` timestamp column might be useful later